# How to avoid Android Studio wrong inspection about parameter X is not used when X is a lambda function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Android studio code inspection warns that "parameter onSelectedChanged is not used" when I call the parameter function as commented below. I could fix the warning by calling the `invoke` method but I wouldn't say I like it.

Is there a better alternative to get rid of the warning?

```
@Composable
fun ProductFilter(
    onSelectedChanged: (ProductFilters) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    FilterChip(
        onClick = {
            onSelectedChanged.invoke(filter)   // Fixed the warning but don't like it :P
            //onSelectedChanged(filter)        // Inspected onSelectedChanged is not used
        },
    )
}
```

Note: It is not a compiler warning so you need to do the "Inspect code..." action on Android Studio to see the warning message.

Comment: What is "X" in your example?

Comment: onSelectedChanged

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242214898?pli=1) on the Google Issue Tracker that seems to describe similar behavior as you are observing.

Please make sure that you are running at least Android Studio Flamingo Patch 1. 
 If your are not, you can download the latest version on the [Android Studio Homepage](https://developer.android.com/studio). Maybe your issue was resolved in a new version as well.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 1

Comment: I [commented](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242214898#comment6) on the Google issue tracker.